# Any Advice on Running dbmail?

Tags: email, postfix

I am trying to setup a dbmail-based email server with dbmail+postfix+mysql (and eventually sasl I guess), however I seem to be unable to send or receive any emails.  All the log files are blank and no emails are sent or received, but I am able to telnet into the POP/SMTP/IMAP servers both locally on the server and remotely on my laptop.

I have basically followed the dbmail wiki install instructions, however they are not always very clear.  (I'm running Debian 6 at the moment)

So, can anyone shed some light on how I might go about getting dbmail up and running?  Any practical experience, links to tutorials, general suggestions, etc. would be most appreciated.

Comment: You might have better luck getting help if you change the title of your question to something more like "Cannot Send/Receive in new dbmail installation on Debian 6". Your current title sounds like you are looking for general best practices, but you are having a concrete problem. Hopefully, this will help get more views. You may also want to add a debian tag to the question and a link to the dbmail instructions you attempted to follow.

Answer (score 0):

When diagnosing problems like this it helps to use telnet to connect to the mail server on port 25.  The required dialog is specified in [RFC2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt).  This will allow you to quickly determine if your server is responding and what error messages if any it is generating.